# VBA - capacity overflow error

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that is causing a

> capacity overflow error type 6

due to the code between `'------------------------------------'`. I will appreciate your help :)!

I was not able to solve it with other discussion.

```
Sub Calculate_Mix()
    Dim rngUsernameHeader As Range
    Dim rngHeaders As Range
    Dim rngAddress As Range
    Dim rng_R1 As Range
    Dim rng_delisted As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim value As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rngHeaders = Range("1:1") 'Looks in entire first row.
    Set rngUsernameHeader = rngHeaders.Find(what:="VAl MAT'Mar18", After:=Cells(1, 1))

    rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
    rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 1).value = "Delisted"

    rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 2).EntireColumn.Insert
    rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 2).value = "New Launches"

    rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 3).EntireColumn.Insert
    rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 3).value = "Price_17"

    rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 4).EntireColumn.Insert
    rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 4).value = "Price_18"

    For Each Cel In Range("F2", Range("F2").End(xlDown))
    If Cel > 0 And Cel.Offset(0, 1) = 0 Then
            Cel.Offset(0, 2).value = Cel.value
    Else: Cel.Offset(0, 2).value = 0
    End If
    If Cel = 0 And Cel.Offset(0, 1) > 0 Then
            Cel.Offset(0, 3).value = Cel.Offset(0, 1).value
    Else: Cel.Offset(0, 3).value = 0
    End If
    Next Cel

    '------------------------------------'
    For Each Cel In Range("H2", Range("H2").End(xlDown))
    If Cel = 0 And Cel.Offset(0, 1) = 0 Then
        value = Cel.Offset(0, -2).value / Cel.Offset(0, -4).value
        Cel.Offset(0, 2).value = value
    Else: Cel.Offset(0, 2).value = 0
    End If
    Next Cel
   '------------------------------------'

End Sub
```

Comment: Does value ever exceed the limits of `Long` variable type?

Comment: Also, does H3 or beyond actually have data in it? Because if not, the code will be processing the *entire rowset of Excel*, which will most likely cause that error.

Answer (score 2):

You've declared `value` (bad variable name, by the way) as `Long`. You'll get an overflow error if you try to assign a decimal value to an integer variable (which may well be happening with this line:

```
value = Cel.Offset(0, -2).value / Cel.Offset(0, -4).value
```

Try declaring `value` as `Double`

Better still, rename and declare `dMyValue` as `Double`